# Adding a trailing slash in Restangular service call to a Go ReST service

Tags: restangular, gorilla

I making the following call using Restangular:

```
Restangular.one('clients', $route.current.params.clientEmail).get();
```

I have a ReST service defined using gorilla:

```
var m *mux.Router
m.HandleFunc("/{clientEmail}/", GetClient).Methods("GET")
```

Note that the service requires a trailing slash.
I need to have Restangular construct the service call so that a trailing slash is included, to delimit the email. 
The way I have it now, the ReST request is like:

```
http://me.com/foo@bar.com
```

I need Restangular to send, note the trailing slash:

```
http://me.com/foo@bar.com/
```

I cannot figure out how to get Restangular to add the trailing slash, do I need to construct the service call differently some how?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try

```
Restangular.one('clients', $route.current.params.clientEmail).one('').get();
```

Answer (score 0):

To your app config,configure Restangular to set request suffixes:

```
angular.module("my_app_module", ["restangular",])
.config(["RestangularProvider",function(RestangularProvider){
    RestangularProvider.setRequestSuffix("/");
}])
```